# Best way to counter Teemo top?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been playing many ranked matches with my main, Wukong, and I cant seem to touch Teemo top.

Any good counters?

Comment: Hi, n1te, welcome to Arqade!  Unfortunately, I am voting to close your question as it is overly broad; as it stands, it's not a good fit to provide a definitive answer.  You may have more luck asking, "What are Teemo's weaknesses?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play a champion that doesn't rely on auto attacks and has a gap closer. The biggest reason Teemo top is good is his blind and his fast movement speed.

Yorick: High harass, Has a slow and a speed boost, and sustain. Shuts down Teemo hard. Use ghouls to push Teemo off all that farm and if Teemo risks the farm drop everything you got on him and charge at him. He can't blind you + 3 ghouls (+ your ult if you thin you got him) I'd also run exhaust on Yorick to really lock down Teemo.

Rumble: Spell based, has a nice speed boost and the slows from harpoon. Teemo's blind is useless on rumble besides being annoying. Yes he is ranged but if he goes in for CS/Harass you can hit him with harpoon, pop W shield/speed boost, and flame spitter him to death.

Most AP Tops are pretty strong vs Teemo due to the use of spells and not relying on auto attacks.

Hope this helped. Have fun!

EDIT: If you really want to play Wukong vs Teemo. Bait some harass out of him with your clone then Q + Hop onto him, or Q + Hop then clone out fast hopefully before his blind comes out or he does a lot of harass. Just play a bit aggressively on him and less on farming. Mercury Treads help remove some of his DoT and Blind damage.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few counters here: http://championselect.net/champ/Teemo

> I can tell you from experience champions that can drop pressure on teemo without relying on being in range for a harass work well.
>
> Alternatively playing champs with sheilds or self heals work well.
>
> The worst thing about Teemo top is his blind and his harass.
>
> The MS and shroom coverage don't help either, but shouldn't be much of a threat initially. 
>   Teemo is pretty squishy until he starts getting CS and kills. Your best bet for top lane vs Teemo is probably the heavy harass or just tower hug till your jungler ganks.
>
> You said you like playing Wu Kong so perhaps just relying on tower hug and last hits will work. At level 6 your ulti + a jungle gank should be more than enough to kill teemo. You only lose your lane when you get killed and you lose CS. Sometimes winning a lane isnt about pushing a tower but about getting the most gold. Try things like gold per 5 (Heart of Gold & Philo stone) they are must haves in most top lanes.
>
> Hope this is helpful and good luck.